# Links to RealmHelps.net

Tags: discussion, copyright

On the same vein of the [question about dndtools](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/links-to-dd-tools-dndtools-eu). Realmhelps.net too have complete description of non-OGL item.

This time the scope of use is way smaller, we have only [39 istances](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3A%22*realmshelps.*%22) where the site is used, in both questions(15) and answers(24).

Comment: yeah, in fact I say we just close this as a dupe of the dndtools question since there's no need to rehash the exact same discussion - it certainly stands in this case as well. I extended the subject line of the other to "and similar sites."

Answer (score 4):

While probably the site won't be closed soon (Wotc have moved on from 3.5 and, as far as I can tell, they are not striking any of the new dndtools clones), I think, for coherence at least, we shouldn't make use of the site.

Comment: Yes, the same reasons as given for dndtools apply here.