# Is recommending an online character generator ok?

Tags: discussion, copyright

Sometimes, I want to link to some online character or NPC generators. However, I know that some of the online resources, especially spell lists, are actually copyright violations.

Are these online generators ok? [Here is an example](http://rpgtinker.com/).

Answer (score 13):

### Recommending *an* online generator is OK.

There's nothing *inherently* wrong with recommending a tool. Keep in mind, though, that [link-only answers are bad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers): you should be explaining in your answer post *why* the sort of resource you recommend is the best solution, such that a future reader who found your link had rotted would still know what they're looking for and why.

### *That* online generator is certainly not good to link to.

That generator's creating characters for D&D 5e.
Any Dungeons and Dragons 5th edition product that's using material beyond the [SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) and isn't licensed to do so by WotC is in violation of US copyright and/or trademark laws unless it falls into one of several narrow categories of works exempt from said laws.

The site you link does not describe a special license agreement, so when the first result I saw included the Goliath playable race--a race not in the SRD--I knew already that it was very probably living outside the law.

[Note that products distributed through [DMs Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/) hew to their own license: read [their help pages](http://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us) for some more info. I've personally found their staff to be very responsive: do reach out to them if something's not clear.]

And [we shouldn't link to resources that we *know* are in violation of US copyright/trademark law.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2773/23970)