# Why is "http://dnd.arkalseif.info" blacklisted?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

The subject web-site is black-listed, which disallows me to save an edit of one of my answers that links to the said web-site. What issues does it have? Should I delete the link from my answer even if I do not apply the edit? A search didn't yield anything.

Answer (score 13):

Arkalseif seems to be a repository of D&D data not belonging to the SRD, i.e. they don't have the licence needed to publish those information on their site.

StackExchange does not support piracy (even if it was not for ethic reasons, [pirated sites are often targeted by cease & desist letters and might therefore be forced to close, causing link rot](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2773/4398).)

Comment: This is correct. It was blacklisted for these reasons.

Answer (score 8):

That domain is one of several that have been blacklisted for the reasons given [in Zachiel's post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7556/1204): it's a piracy site and we don't want links to those on RPG.SE for reasons of ethics and link rot.

The D&D 5e SRD sites are fine and unaffected.

- Please do remove links to blacklisted sites if you find them. Even if that is all you're editing, we'd appreciate it. There are members such as myself working to remove piracy links from the site, so all of them will be gone sooner or later; your help would be appreciated.
- Consider linking instead to one of the many D&D 5e SRD sites available where the same material exists in the SRD: [5esrd.com](https://www.5esrd.com/), [5thsrd.org](https://5thsrd.org/), [Roll20's D&D 5e compendium](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/BookIndex), [Open5e.com](https://open5e.com/), [dnd5e.info](https://dnd5e.info/), or [5e.d20srd.org](http://5e.d20srd.org) *(️ not HTTPS)* to name a few.
- If you want to reference book material that doesn't show up in an SRD, you may use a book title and page reference. Pretend the reader already has the book and can look it up pretty easily. (If they don't have the book, the idea is they need to get it themselves if they need access to the stuff inside it.)
- You may of course [quote part of the text under fair use](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/) for the purposes of analysing text, but reproducing the full text of something like a class feature in full is rarely necessary for analysing it. (The rare exception is usually when there's only a sentence or two in it.)

If somehow we have wound up blacklisting a site that is doing nothing wrong, please let us know, and we will investigate.

Comment: Should http://chisaipete.github.io/ be blacklisted as well?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for bringing that up.