# Are the Pathfinder published materials safe to reference in RPG Main questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, copyright, pathfinder

[This question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-constitutes-copyright-infringement/361#361) touches on the OGL, but talks more about WotC (dnd3.5e) and CC vs. OGL conflict.

Some places I've looked into regarding this:

[Paizo Community Use Policy](http://paizo.com/paizo/about/communityuse) - linked to by [Pathfinder_OGC](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) through Legal Information link.

[Paizo Open Game License](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/openGameLicense.html) page. Specifically this (emphasis mine):

> Product Identity:
>
> > The following items are hereby identified as Product Identity, as defined in the Open Game License 1.0a, Section 1(e), and are **not Open Content: All trademarks, registered trademarks, proper names (characters, deities, etc.), dialogue, plots, storylines, locations, characters, artworks, and trade dress**. (Elements that have previously been designated as Open Game Content are not included in this declaration.)
>
> Open Content:
>
> > **Except for material designated as Product Identity (see above)**, the game mechanics of this Paizo Publishing game product **are Open Game Content**, as defined in the Open Game License version 1.0a Section 1(d). No portion of this work other than the material designated as Open Game Content may be reproduced in any form without written permission.

I am not a lawyer, so I can't be sure, but I *believe* this means I can copy text from the Pathfinder published materials.

It's possible that I can until it's taken down by action from Paizo, but I'd like to never reach that point if such a point exists (and I can always safely reference d20PFSRD, I suppose).

This is my first meta question, so let me know if it's not quite in the right format (or edit it into oblivion).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially: Same answer as [What constitutes copyright infringement?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-constitutes-copyright-infringement)

The site deliberately has no opinion on this, it's up to posters to not plagarize.  Also, the site is not a signatory to the OGL, the Community Use Policy, or any other publisher agreements outside of federal law.

Personal thought: Post brief excerpts of rules, which are likely covered by fair use, and link to fuller stuff where possible.

Answer (score 6):

Building on what mxyzplk's post:

If you post text excerpts, also post where you got the information. Book name, page number, publisher, ect.

Comment: So, use standard citation practices, you mean. It works for academia…