# Does this answer to a question about a Vampire Discipline that lets them disbelieve in things have too much quoted text?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, citations

In the answer to this question [Where can I find this Discipline that allows a Vampire to disbelieve in sunlight, stakes, etc. so strongly that it can ignore them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27754/vampire-discipline-to-disbelieve-in-sunlight-stakes-etc/27755#27755), there is a large block of source book text quoted. As per this Meta question [What constitutes copyright infringement?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-constitutes-copyright-infringement), it sounds like it would be okay until someone from White Wolf complains?

Is there too much text quoted? Should we try to cut down the answer, perhaps removing the actual games rules and just leaving the 'flavor' of the power?

Comment: yes. yes it does.

Comment: @waxeagle Is that better?

Comment: yes. I believe that is. My rule of thumb is a paragraph at a time should be plenty and if I need to include more from the text I should summarize what's relevant.

Comment: Enh. It didn't even have the dice pool required to use the power. I think it was harmless.

Comment: to be clear, my opposition has absolutely nothing to do with copyright/citation issues and everything to do with the fact that large quotations like that aren't a good writing style for SE answers

Comment: Related (for future readers): [Is there any reason why quoting a D&D 5e spell in its entirety would not qualify as “fair use”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8746/33569), [Can non-open-license rules be discussed, or not?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6043/33569)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my strategy for writing answers on all SE sites:

- Use only as much quotation as is absolutely required to make your point.
- It's almost always better to summarize rather than to quote giant chunks because your answer needs to be tailored to answer the question.
- Use integrated quotes when possible as it makes you totally look like you know what you you're doing.
- Approach writing answers like you would for a highschool or college research paper.

That last point is my ultimate piece of advice. Think back to your highschool or college research paper days. Use short quotes, integrated quotes, and links to supporting sources instead of just a giant chunk of text. This tailors your post to your thesis statement (you have a thesis statement right?).

Comment: I wish bullet 4 could be made into policy all over the network.