# Should we be including a whole copyrighted stat block?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, copyright

[How many level 20 PCs with Tiamat (CR 30) on their side would treat Asmodeus (CR 40) as a Hard encounter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89254/23970) reproduces the stat block for Tiamat in its entirety. That struck me as reproducing rather more copyrighted material than is necessary, so I hid it in an HTML comment and left a (mainsite) comment to the effect. (Revision 5)

It's been brought back out into the open. I don't want to start an edit war, but I think something like "I'm using Tiamat's stats from *Rise of Tiamat*" would give potential answerers enough information to go on without reproducing non-SRD material.

**Should this question post that whole stat block?**

Comment: Related (for future readers): [Is there any reason why quoting a D&D 5e spell in its entirety would not qualify as “fair use”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8746/33569), [Does this answer to a question about a Vampire Discipline that lets them disbelieve in things have too much quoted text?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3084/33569), [Can non-open-license rules be discussed, or not?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6043/33569)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No we shouldn't. It doesn't look like the restoration was deliberate though, but instead just an edit conflict while the OP was only trying to add a new paragraph. (I've noticed the automatic edit conflict detection doesn't seem to be as sensitive as it used to be.)

I've re-removed the image and added a note for where they are taking the stats from.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out--I hadn't noticed the *times* of the edits, just the sequence.

Comment: We can only use copyrighted material when it falls strictly into fair use guidelines (Assuming one won't go to `<game studio>` asking - and obtaining - for permission to post stuff here).